# FullCalendar js, creating a drop down event.

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, fullcalendar

I'm currently working on a project using FullCalendar. For each day I have a series of events that are related to each other like this :

**EVENT 1**

subset of event 1

subset of event 1

**EVENT 2**

subset of event 2

subset of event 2

For a total of six events. What I would like to know is if there is the possibility to create a sort of drilldown event. Such as that when I click on that event, It splits in multiple subsets of that event. So my final result would be something like :

**EVENT 1** (when I click on this, it splits and I can see its subset)

**EVENT 2**

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Not using the built-in functionality of fullCalendar, no. You'd very much be on your own with this, unfortunately. You can handle the calendar's "eventClick" callback to detect when a main event was clicked, but after that it's up to you.

Comment: @ADyson Any idea on how to solve that ?

Comment: It's quite a bit of work to do, I guess. Too much for an answer here and anyway your requirements as shown are not detailed enough for anyone to follow and produce a solution.